# Can Ant's tar task set a Linux file permission even when the task is used on other platforms?

Tags: windows, ant, permissions, tar

Starting with Ant 1.7, the TarFileSet is available which seems to allow file permission modifications in the tar archive.

Does this feature work platform-independent, so that I can for example create a tar file on Windows and set execution permissions for script files in this archive which will have this flag if the file is unpacked on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set permissions using [tarfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/tarfileset.html), using the `filemode` and `dirmode` attributes.  This works when creating tar archives, even on windows.

Rather annoyingly though, the [untar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) task does *not* support the reverse operation that you might want:

> File permissions will not be restored
>   on extracted files.

But the permisions are restored fine if you use `tar -xf`, for example.