# Use Maven assembly plugin to set Linux file permissions even when run on other platforms?

Tags: java, maven, file-permissions, tar, maven-assembly-plugin

Similar question: [Can Ant's tar task set a Linux file permission even when the task is used on other platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678403/can-ants-tar-task-set-a-linux-file-permission-even-when-the-task-is-used-on-othe)

If I use Maven 2 assembly plugin with the 'project' descriptor, is there a way to set shell script permissions to executable for example for included build.sh script files?

Example:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This will create three files

- -project.tar.bz2
- -project.tar.gz
- -project-zip

And I would like to set the file permissions for all *.sh files which are in the tar files to 'executable'.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This can be done using the `fileMode` parameter available in Maven Assembly Plugin [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html).  For instance

```
<assembly>
    ...
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
        ...
    </fileSets>
    ...
</assembly>
```

Comment: How does it works if I compile my plugin Eclipse RCp with Tycho? Where do I need to write this files? I've only some pomx.xml file...Is there a "fileMode" with Tycho?

Comment: It sets me bin/ directory to d--------- permissions :\. The files inside are ok.

Comment: This creates the tar with files having 775 permission with all the directories (folders) dont have even read permission (d--------). What should be done for this?

Answer (score 4):

It was asked in comments how to set permisions for directories, so that they don't end up with `d---------` permissions. The answer is pretty straightforward - use `directoryMode`:

```
<assembly>
    ...
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
        </fileSet>
        ...
    </fileSets>
    ...
</assembly>
```