# Set permissions on tar created by maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, file-permissions, maven-assembly-plugin

With the Maven assembly plugin I know I can set the permissions of the files contained within my tar [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719408/use-maven-assembly-plugin-to-set-linux-file-permissions-even-when-run-on-other-p).  However can I use the plugin to set the permissions of the tar itself?

Maybe I should just the ant plugin but this is a little messy

Comment: This is very strange requirements, why you need this? Maven produced artefact are plain files, should be deployed to repositories or published.

Comment: Indeed this is for deployment.  When deployed I want to make sure that different users to be able to untar the tar and dont get permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to use "exec-maven-plugin" to do this.

[How to change permission of jar packaged by maven? I am using maven assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939336/how-to-change-permission-of-jar-packaged-by-maven-i-am-using-maven-assembly-plu)

"Use maven:exec plugin to execute chmod"

So the idea is that you would add another plugin to the pom.xml file that sets the permission on the tar itself.

The only drawback that I see is that you have to have the name of the file in the plugin xml code in the pom file. That's fine as I have that listed in  in the maven-assembly-plugin.  But the file extension is found in assembly.xml (.zip, or .tar-gz), so if you change the file extension in assembly.xml, you would have to remember to change it in the pom.xml file.  Not a big hassle, but it might be easy to miss on your first review.